# If Condition Inside a For Loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a query checking with `$userid`

```
$loginid = 2;
$sql = mysql_query( 'SELECT cc.name, c.fullname, c.userid FROM mdl_course c, mdl_coursecat cc WHERE c.course = cc.id');
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  $userid = $row['userid'];
  echo '<tr><td>';
  if($userid == $loginid)  
  {
    echo '<a href="">go to course</a>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'you dont have permissions to go';
  }
  echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

My problem is that it's not going inside the `else` statement. Could anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Your quotes are a bit messy too...

Comment: I see 2 problems on a quick look: Incorrect quoting in your `else` block, not using `mysql_fetch_object` but directly iterating over the mysql result resource (which you cannot do). IF you used an editor with syntax highlighting, the quote issue would be easy to spot...

Comment: I think the code is correct now, Why my else statement isnot working here, it shows empty

Answer (score 2):

The first very big problem is that you use `$sql` as an array but [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) return a resource. What you need is to use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). Anyway because `$ss` will be an element of the array you have to use it according to its type (array and not object). Thus, you should have something like:

```
while ($ss = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
   $userid = $ss['userid'];

   // Do other stuff
}
```

The second one is that you have not escaped the single quote inside your sentence in the `else`.

Comment: Could you give suggestion, why my else statement isn't wotking, it shows empty td

Comment: @user1067018 What do you see if before the IF you put var_dump($userid); ?

Comment: @user1067018 I suggest you to do var_dump($userid); var_dump($loginid); var_dump($userid == $loginid) to understand what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `foreach($sql as $ss)` with `while($ss = mysql_fetch_object($sql))`. Then the loop will actually work. You cannot iterate over a mysql resultset directly but need to use one of the `mysql_fetch_*` functions to retrieve a row.

To get rid of the syntax error, replace `echo 'you don't have permissions to go';` with `echo 'you don\'t have permissions to go';` or `echo "you don't have permissions to go";`.

Comment: Actually that isn't the problem Iam getting, Iam able to get the output correctly, only else isn't working. (The typing mistake in Stack overflow)

Answer (score 1):

i'd say the problem lies here:

```
while($row = $mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

as `mysql_fetch_array()` is a function, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here: `echo 'you don't have permissions to go';`
Replace with `echo 'you don\'t have permissions to go';`
It sees the apostrophe of `don't` as end of string

Comment: I have corrected everything, it displays only for the first row and rest of the rows are empty. Could anyone help me